# Install on linux without sudo?

Tags: installation

I'm using a shared cluster (running Ubuntu 16.04) upon which I don't have sudo access. Is there anyway I can still install Mathematica to `/usr/local/Wolfram`? If I use another path will everything still function properly?

After proceeding and using my home directory, I recieved this warning:

> WARNING: Avahi Daemon is not active on your system so some Kernel
>   Discovery features will not be available.

Comment: I am also interested in an answer to this. Did you solve it?

Comment: The warning message regarding Avahi Daemon looks quite innocuous to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different path, for example `/home/user5601/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3` as the installation directory. When asked where to put the executables, you can select `/home/user5601/bin` (assuming this directory exists). Then make sure to add `/home/user5601/bin` to your path. Done.